# React cant change return data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to do a helper function to check if login or not in react and nodejs... in nodejs everything is fine but I have problems at reactside to get value outside of function with return:

> return output always = undefined ...

Here is the function;

> note: console.log (response)  = {status: 200, data: true, error:
> false}

```
import axios                from "axios";
import { useState,useEffect }   from 'react';

export const AuthController = (event) => {

    let data = {data : localStorage.getItem("imtakilogintoken")}
    async function getData() {
        try {
        let res = await axios({
                url: 'http://localhost:3005/profile',
                method: 'post',
                timeout: 8000,
                data    :data,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                }
            })
            return {
                status  : res.status,
                data    : res.data,
                error   : false
            }
        }
        catch (err) {
            return {
                status  : false,
                data    : false,
                error   : err
            }
        }
    }
    var output;
    
    useEffect(() => {
        getData().then(response => {
            console.log (response)

             output = response;
        })
    }, []);

    return output;

}
```

Comment: 1) output is returned from this function before you get the data from axios. 2) output variable is not a state or ref variable It will be just lost. How are you planning to use this function. What is the output you expect? Probably you want to change `var output` to `const [output, setOutput] = useState()` and `setOutput(response)`.

Comment: I'd use a hook instead: https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-goodall-z4ecyh?file=/src/useAuth.js

Comment: yes it works with that way. I know it but this time I couldnt stop the call function twice.. first on load and than on setstate works.. all the time it works twice

Comment: Also @ChrisG way is same and this time it call the function third time on load for eacth setstate... so it is normal?

Comment: On App page if I put alert("123") it always callling as the count of setstate at helper.

Comment: Is `AuthController` a component ? If so, why does it accept an event instead of props ?

Comment: it is not component it will control everytime app render if login or not

Answer (score 0):

For your kind information `useEffect()` is async function, the control first going to return statement and at this time `return output (undefined)` having `undefined`.
I think here no need to wrap your function into `useEffect()` instead just return from then only. so code would look like below.

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useState,useEffect }   from 'react';

export const AuthController = (event) => {

let data = {data : localStorage.getItem("imtakilogintoken")}
async function getData() {
    try {
    let res = await axios({
            url: 'http://localhost:3005/profile',
            method: 'post',
            timeout: 8000,
            data    :data,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
        })
        return {
            status  : res.status,
            data    : res.data,
            error   : false
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
        return {
            status  : false,
            data    : false,
            error   : err
        }
    }
}
//var output;

getData().then(response => {
     console.log (response)
     return response;
}).catch(err=>{
    return err;
})
```

}

Comment: I tried that also but return for this only return for them self not for "AuthController" Function

Comment: `return`ing inside a callback does nothing

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem itself is how you are trying to reach the data, on react I will recommend you to create a custom hook that you can implement on any component that loads later on the app, something like this:

```
import { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const useAuthControl = () => {
    
   

    const [hasResponse, setResponse] = useState(null);
 

    const getData = useCallback(
        async (data) => {
            try {
        let res = await axios({
                url: 'http://localhost:3005/profile',
                method: 'post',
                timeout: 8000,
                data    :data,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                }
            })
            setResponse({
                status  : res.status,
                data    : res.data,
                error   : false
            })
        }
        catch (err) {
            setResponse({
                status  : false,
                data    : false,
                error   : err
            })
        }
        },
        []
    );

    return [getData, {hasResponse}];
};

export default useAuthControl;
```